# Moving a Web Application from One server farm to another server farm

Tags: 2007, web-application, virtual-machine

We have a Virtual Machine "vDemo" which is acting like our development server, then me as a developer has a copy of it on my PC, however my copy is very old and development server does have other updates by other developers on it.

Now problem is, "vDemo" has a web application named which is in french language and it also has custom asp.net applications related to it. Now what would be the best option for me to copy this web application to my personal virtual machine. I would like to hear best practices and honestly don't answer if you actually never came accross this scenario before in short "no googling at all please"

**Edit**

I already installed French language pack on my Virtual machine server and got all custom layout site templates and images as well from vDemo server.

I can see the web application has its own content Database and I can maybe copy this content DB and create a new web application in my personal server but I am not sure how it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are pretty much on the right track.

1. Make sure that your VM is at the same level as your production. You
   can check the SharePoint versions by going into the **Operations**
   tab, and under **Topology and Services**, select **Servers in
   Farm**.
2. Install the language pack on your personal VM.
3. Create a new web application in your personal VM.
4. Install all the WSPs and other farm configurations necessary (like custom web.config entries, property bags etc).
5. Copy the content dbs from production to personal VM.
6. Restore the Content dbs in your VM's SQL server.
7. Attach the Content dbs with the specific Web application using stsadm [AddContentDB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263422%28v=office.12%29.aspx) command.
8. Start browsing :)

Let me know if you have face any issues!

Comment: I followed almost all of above steps but unfortunately I installed wrong version of SharePoint patch on my VPC then one was on production which broke SharePoint on my VPC completely, however I got another copy of VPC and will start from scratch and will let you know if came across any other issue, thanks :)

Comment: Install the correct SP or patches. See the version numbers for more details:http://www.chrismcnulty.net/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=6