# Error while attaching content db to a different server

Tags: 2007, development, web-application, content-database

I got back up of content db from a demo server and trying to attach it to a newly created web application in my personal copy of same demo server but not up to date. however I am getting this error,

> WSS_Content_MyTempContent on ServerName contains user-defined schema.
> Databases must b e empty before they can be used.  Delete all of the
> tables, stored procedures an d other objects or use a different
> database.

I tried STSADM command as well doing it through CA but no luck and same error, however If I try to give a new named Content DB to web application it does creates a new content db and gets attached to it and

> If I remove just newly created Content DB from same web application
> using CA and then try to add it again to same web app it gives me same
> error I mentioned above, Strange ini !

Now if I forget what happened and try to create a new site collection using a new content db attached to web application (web application created it itself) then I get another error which is,

> The site /sites/rawr could not be created.  The following exception
> occured: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E14.

Also in ULS log next to this log I find this ugly log entry,

> Unexpected query execution failure, error code 8162. Additional error
> information from SQL Server is included below. "The formal parameter
> "@EnableAudit" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual
> parameter passed in requested output." Query text (if available): "SET
> NOCOUNT ON; DECLARE @DN nvarchar(256),@LN nvarchar(128),@@DocUIVersion
> int,@@Level tinyint,@@S uniqueidentifier; DECLARE @ItemId int; DECLARE
> @@iRet int; DECLARE @ExtraItemSize int; DECLARE @Login nvarchar(255);
> DECLARE @Title nvarchar(255); DECLARE @Email nvarchar(255); DECLARE
> @Notes nvarchar(1023); DECLARE @AddedToTable bit; DECLARE @UserIdOut
> int; DECLARE @LoginOut nvarchar(255); DECLARE @TitleOut nvarchar(255);
> DECLARE @EmailOut nvarchar(255); DECLARE @NotesOut nvarchar(1023);
> DECLARE @DeletedOut bit; DECLARE @IsGroup bit; SET @IsGroup = 0; SET
> @@Level = 1; SELECT @Login = ?; SELECT @Title = ?; SELECT @Email = ?;
> SELECT @Notes = ?; SELECT @@S=?; BEGIN TRAN; EXEC @@iRet =
> proc_SecAddUser @@S, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, @Login, @Title, @Email, @Notes, ?,
> ?, ?, @AddedToTable OUTPUT, @UserIdOut OUTPUT, @LoginOut OUTPUT,
> @TitleOut OUTPUT, @EmailOut OUTPUT, @NotesOut OUTPUT, @DeletedOut; IF
> @@iRet <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN; GOTO DONE; END ; SELECT @ItemId =
> @UserIdOut ; COMMIT TRAN; DONE: SELECT @@iRet, @ItemId, @AddedToTable,
> @LoginOut, @TitleOut, @EmailOut, @NotesOut, @DeletedOut "

I am ashamed to mention that since my server is a very very very old copy of "vdemo server" so I copied Template folder and pasted it into my local virtual server,

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server
> extensions\12\TEMPLATE

I copied it because original vdemo server has custom site templates that I needed on my personal server copy, now web application i already have here is working and I don't see any errors.

What I actually was trying to do is described here [Moving a Web Application from One server farm to another server farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53352/moving-a-web-application-from-one-server-farm-to-another-server-farm)

After doing research on Google I realized that when we create a new DB or attach one it asks for Select Search Server which I did selected one we have and for some I didn't so not sure if problem is related to that or something (like I have to delete Content DB that I created myself)

**EDIT**

With help of [Arsalan Adam Khatri](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/4100/arsalan-adam-khatri)  I figured out my servers CA got different versions so trying to download hot fixes and Service pack 2 from  [this link hotfixes](http://www.easysharepoint.net/hotfixes.html) but I am not able to find download option for hot fix  [981042](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981042)

**EDIT 2**

After installation of WSS 3 SP 2 (SP2) it started Configuration wizard and failing with error,

> Failed to initiate the upgrade sequence.
>
> An exception of type System.Data.SQLClient.SQLException was thrown.
> Additional exception information Cannot find the object "SiteDeletion"
> because it doesnot exist or you do not have persmissions

Now I am administrator of everything..

Comment: Are both your servers patched the same version number/CU level?

Comment: Nice Catch James :), trying to get hot fixes and then will see if it works !

Comment: SharePoint 2010 helpfully tells you if it can't upgrade/attach DBs because of version numbers being way out of sync, I can't remember if SP2007 does that though.

Comment: Re your Edit: download for that hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=981042&kbln=en-us

Comment: SharePoint 2007 says, "Delete all tables, Stored Procedures and ...." Loooooool

Comment: @JamesLove got exception, I edited my question again :(

Comment: Did you run the config wizard as administrator (right click, Run As)?

Comment: Config wizard is in start menu and doesn't have "Run As" option in it, however I am logged in as administrator tho and it worked before