# Pre Requesties for wss-kb981043-fullfile-x86-glb.exe

Tags: 2007, migration, content-database, service-pack, hotfix

I updated my Machine with MOSS service pack 2 and trying to install wss-kb981043-fullfile-x86-glb.exe but it's giving error, not sure what am I missing however I am getting different exception messages as explained in [Error while attaching content db to a different server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/error-while-attaching-content-db-to-a-different-server) question of mine.

Error while installing,

[image: Error]

Comment: Is your server X86 or x64 ?

Comment: its 32 bit (x86)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be missing a prerequesite to the patch...Do you have Service Pack 1 installed? Also, did you run the SharePoint Product Configuration Service before trying? You have to apply the hotfix after the MOSS SP2 is completely installed.

Comment: I am getting errors for PSConfig and other errors as explained in my earlier question :(